# erro ao carregar informações no select

Tags: php, html

Tenho esse código que teria que carregar um select e logo abaixo um teria um textarea, porém, depois que coloquei o código php para preencher o select, sumiu meu textarea e não consigo identificar o motivo.

```html
<?php $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, descricao FROM produto"); ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="produto" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Produto</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control" name="produto" id="produto">
                <option>Selecione...</option>
                <?php while($prod = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $prod['id'] ?>"><?php echo $prod['descricao'] ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="pessoaObservacoes" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Observações</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="pessoaObservacoes" id="pessoaObservacoes" placeholder="Observações" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ó o textarea aí?!

Comment: Não é o ponto e virgula que você esqueceu aqui?  Obs: eu adicionei                              <option value="<?php echo $prod['id']; ?>"><?php echo $prod['descricao']; ?></option>

Comment: Não, já coloquei esses ponto e virgula, mais continuou com o mesmo problema.

Comment: A partir de que ponto o código não carrega mais? Os options são todos preenchidos com os valores corretos? Qual versão de PHP você usa?

Comment: Seu textarea sumiu por que tem algum erro no seu código, vai usando o `echo` em cada linha para saber onde possa estar o problema.

Comment: A versão do meu PHP é 7.0.13. O option não carrega as informações do banco. A aplicação carrega só o option sem as informações do banco. O problema é que não aparece nenhum código de erro.